# How to get the information of directories in CVS

Tags: cvs

What cvs command can get the information of directories.
I want to get the creator and crearion time of a folder.
but i can not find what command will work
Can anyone tell me about it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: CVS works on files. It doesn't track directories, so you can't get that sort of information. You may have to infer it from the files within the folder you are interested in.